# disable ASP.NET minification

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-config, bundling-and-minification, asp.net-bundling

I use asp.net bundling and minification. I want to be able to disable minification from *.config file (not from cs-code). As I know i can do it if I change debug attribute in compilation tag from Web.config:

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

But It is not right way because debug flag is responsible not only for  minification. Maybe there is another way to enable/disable minification from config?

Comment: That is the setting that controls the `EnableOptimizations` flag on the `BundleTable`.  As you said, you can do it from cs code by setting  `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;`  However, I do not believe there is a separate config

Answer (score 0):

Here is what this article says:-

> To enable bundling and minification, set the debug value to "false".
>   You can override the Web.config setting with the EnableOptimizations
>   property on the BundleTable class.

[Here is the link](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification)

Answer (score 0):

Just create your own custom web.config app setting, then get this setting at runtime and use it to set the value of the `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations` flag.

ie (this sets True/False based on debug state if no setting is found):

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = 
   Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseMinification"] 
       ?? HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled ? "False" : "True");
```

Or if you want to use the default bundling behavior if there is no entry configured in your web.config

```
bool useMinification = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseMinification"];
if (!string.IsNullOrWhitespace(useMinification))
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = Convert.ToBoolean(useMinification);
```